# Group by Concat Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a problem with a table, I would like to concat a string field using a group by. I have this situation here:

```
USER | TEXT
A    | 'hello'
A    | 'by'
B    | 'hi'
B    | '9'
B    | 'city'
```

I would like to obtain this result:

```
USER | TEXT
A    | 'hello by'
B    | 'hi 9 city'
```

Comment: A recursive cte?

Comment: On a sidenote: there is no column indicating an order, so you may just as well end up with 'by hello' and '9 city hi'.

Answer (score 12):

You can try using xmlagg

```
SELECT
   User
  ,TRIM(TRAILING ' ' FROM (XMLAGG(TRIM(text)|| ','
                           ORDER BY ColumnPosition) (VARCHAR(1000))))
FROM table
GROUP BY 1
```